# Use row and columns indices in matrix to extract values from matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a Matrix A which looks like

```
A = matrix(1:9,3,3)
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

and a matrix of indices of elements I am interested in. Column 1 contains row indices, and column 2 contains column indices:

```
v = matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
v
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    2    3
```

I want to use the rows and column indices in 'v' to extract numbers from 'A'; the indices correspond to the numbers 4 (`A[1, 2]`), 6 (`A[3, 2]`) and 8.

How can I extract those numbers directly from 'A' without using a loop?

When I use

```
A[v[ , 1], v[ , 2]]
```

I get

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    7
[2,]    6    6    9
[3,]    5    5    8
```

because R takes all combinations of the first and second column of 'v'.

What I want is an expression which gives me directly 4, 6, 8.

I could just take the diagonal elements but there must be an easier way.

Comment: You're going to kick yourself: `A[v]`

Comment: Thanks,yes, definitely, I was sure to have tried that one first ;-)

Comment: Are you ok with me deleting this question, gven you have 101k as reputation?

Comment: It's not about reputation. Delete only if you feel it wasn't a worthwhile question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `?"["`, you will find the following:

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

and later on...

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector. Negative indices are not allowed in the index matrix. NA and zero values are allowed: rows of an index matrix containing a zero are ignored, whereas rows containing an NA produce an NA in the result.

Thus, what you are looking for is simply:

```
A[v]
```

Comment: it works when i want to extract rows, but not for columns. wondering why. in ,my case `model=c(6,7,8)`. `diabetes_test[model]` gives me the 6th, 7th and 8th row, but `diabetes_test[,model]` does not give me the 6th, 7th and the 8th column

Comment: This answer alludes to using a matrix with 2 columns to extract row and column combinations instead of a vector, which can only extract either rows or columns. Try `model=matrix(c(6,7,8,6,7,8), ncol=2)` and then `diabetes_test[model]`.