# Taking a data.table slice with a sequence of (row,col) indices

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, matrix-indexing

I have a `data.table` that resembles the one below.

```
tab <- data.table(a = c(NA, 42190, NA), b = c(42190, 42190, NA), c = c(40570, 42190, NA))
tab
       a     b     c
1:    NA 42190 40570
2: 42190 42190 42190
3:    NA    NA    NA
```

Upon specification of a vector of row indices, and a vector of column indices, I would like a vector returned containing the points in `tab` corresponding to the specified vector of row indices and column indices.

For example, suppose I wanted to get the diagonal elements in `tab`. I would specify two vectors,

```
ri <- 1:3
ci <- 1:3
```

and some function, `function(ri, ci, tab)`, would return the diagonal elements of `tab`.

If `tab` were a `data.frame`, I would do what's below,

```
as.data.frame(tab)[cbind(ri, ci)]
```

but, I would like to avoid `data.frame` syntax. I would also like to avoid a `for` loop, as this tends to be slow.

Comment: maybe melt into a long format and set key?

Comment: Here are similar questions for looking up a matrix with a vector of row,col-indices: [Subsetting a matrix using a vector of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921589/subsetting-a-matrix-using-a-vector-of-indices), [Use indices in vector to extract elements from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828165/use-indices-in-vector-to-extract-elements-from-matrix)

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12. Ideally, the solution would avoid transformation, and would be a direct index.

Comment: If you are dealing with all numeric data you're better off working with a `matrix` from the start. The indexing method you show on a matrix is very fast.

Comment: agree with @thelatemail that for the size of the data and number of subsetting calls, it is probably faster to use matrix. but i still believe that there will be a cross over point when data.table will be faster.

Comment: @chinsoon12: for sure; but if matrix suits the OP's task, they could make it the primary data-structure. If anyone has the energy to plot it, I'm curious what the graph looks like of DT vs matrix vs Matrix, for indexing an nxn with n arbitrary (row,col) indices.

Comment: I would have titled this *"Taking a DT/matrix slice with a sequence of (row,col) indices"*

Comment: Thanks @smci, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a faster way to do this than coercing to either matrix or data.frame. Just use the `[data.frame` function.

```
`[.data.frame`( tab,  cbind(ri,ci) )
[1]    NA 42190    NA
```

This is the functional syntax for the `[.data.frame` function.

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain in your answer why `[.data.frame` works natively on a data.table, and link to [its doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/Extract.data.frame)?

Comment: R functions are dispatched by the class of their first argument. Run  `class(DT)` and you get `[1] "data.table" "data.frame"`. Since the "[" function is generic and has a dataframe method, i.e. the `{.data.frame` function. So the interpreter passes a data.table object to the code of that function rather than to `[.data.table`. Look at the output from `methods(`[`)`

Answer (score 4):

(UPDATE: @42-'s answer using  [`[.data.frame`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/Extract.data.frame) is best. But here's my previous answer)

```
as.matrix(tab)[cbind(ri, ci)]
```

is going to be faster and more memory-efficient than `melt`.

I see no reason you don't declare your DT as a matrix, as @thelatemail recommends. This is one case where DT syntax is not as powerful as matrix.

(For memory-efficiency with large DTs, data.table has commands `setDF`/`setDT` to allow converting to/from DF/DT without copying, but I'm not aware it has an equivalent for matrix. If that is something people do a lot of, it might make a good enhance request for DT.

For really big dimensions, you might look into [Matrix's sparse-matrix formats](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix) package), or chunk your data, or use disk-backed data structures.)

Comment: Absolutely. matrix-indexing is one of the most overlooked functions of R imho.

Comment: Thanks @smci. `tab` is derived from a subset of a `data.table`, which is why I don't use a matrix to start. Is it quick going from a `data.table` to a matrix?

Comment: @JoshuaDaly: `as.matrix()` should be pretty fast, how large are your dimensions? If things get really big, you might look into Matrix's sparse-matrix formats, or chunk your data, or use disk-backed data structures.

Comment: Thanks @smci, fortunately it's not too big (8 x 4 `data.table`), but, I will be performing the operation many times, so, I would like to avoid as much overhead as possible. But, your answer is excellent, and covers what to do when the data gets bigger, and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Cool. Take a look at [`Matrix`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix) package

Comment: Coercion is an unnecessary step. Leave it as a data.table (which inherits from data.frame) and use the function that is designed for data.frames.

Comment: @42- Awesome, didn't know of [`[.data.frame`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/Extract.data.frame) until now.